# Specifically target Android devices

Tags: android, ios, android-layout

How do I specifically target Android devices without disturbing the `iOS` devices ?

I know that we can target the mobile devices using

```
 @media all and (max-width: 320px) { }<br/>
 @media all and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 640px) { }<br/>
 @media all and (max-width: 641px) and (max-width: 768px) { }
```

But I don't want to do it this way by getting the screen resolution.
Instead I want to do it by loading different `css` based on `Android` specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the userAgent:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/android/)) {
    console.log("uses android")
    //alert("uses android"), load your css here.
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/iphone/) || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/ipad/)) {
        console.log("uses iphone") //load your css here
    } else { 
    //alert("browser, blackberry or whatever") load your css here
    }
```

**Update**

Jsfiddle: [There you go.](http://jsfiddle.net/XKuuX/)

Comment: I am not a JS dev. So, could you please jsfidddle this how to use on a html page? Thanks in adcance.

Comment: I am using the useragent addon for firefox, and whatever useragent I change, it says 'browser, blackberry or whatever' not loading the respective css

Comment: I never used that plugin, don't know if it works. I'm 100% sure that if you run that in your phone it will work.